# ASP delete button to refresh ModalPopup after click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, modalpopup

I have ModalPopupExtenders that show associations that are NOT tied to a specific product. The associations that ARE tied to the product are shown in a tabcontainer with delete imagebuttons next to them. When I was testing earlier I noticed that the associations that I delete from the tabcontainer don't show up in the modal unless I click on the refresh button in my browser. Is there some code I could use that would make it so that when I click on the delete button, it will automatically refresh my Modal so that I won't have that extra step?

```
<!-- Targets -->
<asp:TabPanel ID="tab8" runat="server" HeaderText="Targets">
<HeaderTemplate>Targets</HeaderTemplate>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ul class="info">
        <asp:ListView ID="lvTargets" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsTargets" DataKeyNames="TargetID">   
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li><%# Eval("TargetName")%>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteTargetButton" runat="server" Style="float:right;" AlternateText="" ImageUrl="../../images/delete.png" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this target audience?')" />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </ul>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>

 <!-- Add a Target -->
      <li>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="TargetButton" runat="server">Target</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:Panel ID="TargetPanel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxAddTarget" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsNewTargets" DataTextField="TargetName" DataValueField="TargetID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitTargets" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelSubmitTargets" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="TargetModal" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="CancelSubmitTargets" DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="TargetPanel" TargetControlID="TargetButton"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    </li>

    Protected Sub SubmitTargets_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitTargets.Click
    DocumentModal.Hide()
    dsNewTargets.DataBind()
    For Each Target As ListItem In cbxAddTarget.Items
        If Target.Selected Then
            Dim sqlAddTarget As String = Nothing
            'SQL INSERT: TargetLink Table
            sqlAddTarget = "INSERT INTO TargetLink (ProductID, TargetID) VALUES (" & ProductID.Value & ", " & Target.Value & ")"
            sqlAddTarget.Replace("'", "''")
            Dim SqlConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=off-db1;uid=productsDB_admin;pwd=******;database=Products")
            SqlConnection.Open()
            Dim sqlCommand As New SqlCommand(sqlAddTarget, SqlConnection)
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            SqlConnection.Close()
        End If
    Next
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)
End Sub   

    Protected Sub dsTargets_Deleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
        'rebind the new targets list to show updates
        dsNewTargets.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do. When you delete items from the tab container, try rebinding the datasource control that's feeding the add target list, like this:

```
//code to delete targets from tab container

dsNewTargets.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**: Added method for rebinding with delete through datasource control.

Add an OnDeleted event handler for dsTargets (the one you're deleting from).

```
Protected Sub dsTargets_Deleted(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    If e.Exception Is Nothing Then
        'rebind the new targets list to show updates
        dsNewTargets.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Data source control might be caching results. Added code to disable caching.

Try adding the following line to your Page_Load event:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
```

Comment: @jlg: I swear I'm not cyber-stalking your questions :)

Comment: LOL! If you have all the answers, be my guest! You may just end up finishing my site for me!

Comment: `code    Protected Sub SubmitTargets_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitTargets.Click
        DocumentModal.Hide()
        dsNewTargets.DataBind()` This is the only thing I can think of out of what you said. The delete isn't happening in the code behind, it's just the button that is doing it. But this way doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like it is refreshing the page, but the modal is still not showing the recently deleted item until I hit refresh on the browser. See edits above

Comment: @jlg: I think you're results might be cached. See edited answer.

Comment: it is still not getting that deleted item back to the modal. I added the nocache code to my page_load but I don't think it is working.

Comment: Is there a way to refresh the entire page? When I add a target, it actually refreshes the entire page and I end up on the first tab in my tabcontainer (Targets is #7). How can I get my delete button to act like my add button?

Comment: I'm assuming that the delete button is in an update panel and uses Ajax? If you have a script manager declared on the page, try setting EnablePartialRendering to false, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @jlg: It actually just occurred to me that you're probably having this problem because the delete is AJAX, and the tab container is not AJAX. Try putting the tab container in an update panel, and add a postback trigger for the tab container (so it posts back when you click something). That way, the AJAX delete can update the tab container, but the tab container can still post back.

Comment: Adding that stuff to the Script Manager didn't work so I will try putting the tab panels in update panels and see what happens.

Comment: The UpdatePanel control is not working. It says that the tabPanel is not a known element. I've tried moving it to different spots inside the tabPanel and outside of the entire TabContainer but nothing is working. I'm not sure why my sites always have to be so complicated!

Comment: Add the trigger to the tab container. The tab panel is not a known element because it's nested in the container.

Comment: I have never used UpdatePanels or PostBackTriggers before so I'm probably doing this wrong. Here is what I have: `code     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers><asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="TabContainer1" /></Triggers>
<!-- Start TabContainer -->
    <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="675px" 
        Height="545px" Font-Underline="false" Enabled="true" EnableTheming="true" 
        ScrollBars="Auto" EnableViewState="False">`

Comment: But what do I put in the code behind? I'm just looking at a tutorial and it's not really clicking yet

Comment: @jlg: Almost. The tab container needs to go in the ContentTemplate.

Comment: If this works correctly, you might not need to put anything in the code behind. By adding the update panel, you're allowing the tab container to be updated via Ajax.

Comment: Ok, so I just thought of something. The adds are in a tabcontainer that is not part of the main tabcontainer. The main tabcontainer shows the product information (Targets....) and the add tabcontainer is just for adding new targets and such to that product. I tried putting update panels around both of them, but it still doesn't work. Is it not possible to get both tabcontainers to update at the same time?

Comment: Since this is becoming quite a pain to try and solve, I am going to move on to other areas of the site that are more important. In actuality, who is going to delete a target association and then want to re-add it before the page gets refreshed again anyway?